# Extract the number following a certain string in R

Tags: r, string

If I have a string in R, say,

```
x1 <- "abcAGE 13 dafkdj"  # I want to get 13
```

and I want to extract that number 13 following "AGE" from it. It is possible the number has one digit or many digits. It is also possible there is no space after "AGE" and no space after "13". For example,

```
x2 <- "abcAGE7 dafkdj"  # I want to get 7
x3 <- "abcAGE 189dafkdj"  # I want to get 189
```

How do I get that number in R? Thanks.

Now if the string has two "AGE"s, for example,

```
x4 <- "abcAGE7 dafkdjAGE25ijdfkdf"  # I want to get 7 and 25
```

how do I get both numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sHere's an option using `sub` and extracting a capture group:

```
> sub(".*AGE ?(\\d+).*", "\\1", x1)
[1] "13"
> sub(".*AGE ?(\\d+).*", "\\1", x2)
[1] "7"
> sub(".*AGE ?(\\d+).*", "\\1", x3)
[1] "189"
```

Wrap it in `as.numeric`/`as.integer` to convert as required.

For the slightly more complicated case of `x4` you can use

```
trimws(regmatches(x4, gregexpr("(?<=AGE) ?\\d+", x4, perl=TRUE))[[1]])
[1] "7"  "25"
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I have a second follow-up question and I modified my original post.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!